# Column names in result and rotate part of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, information-schema

The following a table structure:

```
'----ID-----'----NAME----'----FIELD1----'----FIELD2----'
'     1     '    val     '     123      '      321    '
'     2     '    val2    '     234      '      212    '
```

Need to get the following result:

```
'----ID-----'----NAME----'----FIELDS----'----VALUES----'
'     1     '    val     '    FIELD1    '      123     '
'     1     '    val     '    FIELD2    '      321     '
'     2     '    val2    '    FIELD1    '      234     '
'     2     '    val2    '    FIELD2    '      212     '
```

How write this query? I can get column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. But how to join table with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`? Also how can rotating a part of table?

As living example. Following is table:

[image]

On screenshot only several fields but in table there are a lot of fields. I wrote the following query:

```
Select p.GUID, p.myvalues, p.Fields 
from myTable gz
unpivot( [myvalues] for Fields in ([area], [davlplastmax])) p
```

But this query doesn't return null values.

Also I want get columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and past them in `([area], [davlplastmax])`.

For example:

```
unpivot( [values] for Fields in (
    SELECT [MyDb].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM [MyDb].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'MyTable'
)
```

Comment: You can use CASE or UNPIVOT statements.

Comment: UNPIVOT seems to be the way to go as some have already answered. Question: why are you trying to join to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Answer (score 2):

Unpivot?

```
select u.id, u.name, u.fields, u.values
from MyTable t
unpivot
(
  values
  for fields in (Field1, Field2)
) u;
```

Comment: Thank for answer. I supplemented the question.Pleace look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpivot as below:

```
Select * from #data
unpivot( [values] for Fields in ([Field1],[Field2])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| Id | Name | values | Fields |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | val  |    123 | Field1 |
|  1 | val  |    321 | Field2 |
|  2 | val2 |    234 | Field1 |
|  2 | val2 |    212 | Field2 |
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

You can use dynamic query as below for getting columns from Information_Schemas

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(Column_Name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'TestData'
        and COLUMN_NAME not in ('Id','Name') for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = '   Select * from
    (Select * from #data )a
    unpivot( [values] for Fields in (' + @cols1+ ')) p '

Exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Comment: Thank for answer. I supplemented the question.Pleace look.

Comment: Updated my query accordingly